# dojo query on widgets

Tags: javascript, widget, dojo

Can the [`dojo.query`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/query) function be used to lookup widgets with certain attributes?

for instance, if I want to get a list of all input widgets with type hidden. It seems to me that dojo.query only works for DOM objects and is not meant to be used with objects. Is this correct?

For instance `dojo.query('input[type=hidden]')` would normally work for regular HTML input fields but does not work for Dojo ones especially that they tend to be wrapped in DIVs, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right.
For dijit, use dijit.registry to lookup the widgets in your page : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/registry.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with it and hopefully it can do what I need it to.

Comment: If you use firebug, the dojo extension can help : http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/DojoFirebugExtension_Reference_Guide

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify nodes for dojo.query to search on.

I.E.

```
dojo.query('input[type=hidden]', widgetObject.domNode);
```

this may help, just throwing it out there

Comment: Note that if the widget has already been removed from the page (e.g. closed tab) then `widgetObject.domNode` may be null, and your query will find *all* hidden-inputs across the whole page, which may cause some fun bugs.